# Should we create a new tag for the questions about the Israel-Gaza Conflict

Tags: discussion, tags

This conflict is pretty much as old as Israel itself, but has flared up and spawned several questions lately.

Should we create a tag for questions about this conflict?  If so what should it be?  If it already exists what is it?

Answer (score 1):

I would say No - it generally falls under the existing Israel & Palestinan Conflict tags.

I can't imagine a scenario in which a person is interested in this conflict, but not in israeli-palestian issues generally.  Tags really have one use - they let you filter out the traffic you aren't interested in.  I would be highly skeptical that *this* conflict in particular is different than the context around it.

Comment: which tags specifically are you talking about?